# Jquery select2 select2-search__field wrong size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-select2

I'm working on a bootstrap template and I'm using select2 with bootstrap theme. I have multiple collapsible panels with the select2 inside. The first panel is visible with 3 `col-md-4` (one for each select) and the `select2-search__field` gets a `width: 518px` All the other panels are collapsed, with the same number of columns and the `select2-search__field` gets a `width: 100%` rule. This is kinda annoying because when I open the collapsed panel I see this:

[image]

instead of this:

[image]

Can anyone explain me how to fix this problem? Is a simple css problem?

Thanks in advance for your answers

**EDIT:**
I'm adding the hidden panel code, I've omitted the `.panel-group` and `.panel-heading` divs:

```
<div id="option-group" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <select class="form-control autocomplete" name="id_material" data-placeholder="Select material" multiple></select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <select class="form-control autocomplete" name="id_color" data-placeholder="Select color" multiple></select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <select class="form-control autocomplete" name="id_detail" data-placeholder="Select detail" multiple></select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you're saying the placeholder is being partially covered? You would need to replicate in a code snippet so we can have a look how everything is interacting.

Comment: Placeholder is partially covered because `select2-search__field` has a wrong width... Anyway I'll edit my answer including the code

Comment: The code doesn't help without the CSS, as this is most likely a CSS issue. A JSFiddle or similar with the problem in it would allow someone to pinpoint the rules affecting your select2.

Comment: I'm using the default css for bootstrap and bootstrap theme for select2... Anyway I will add the fiddle later, thank you for your suggestions